# preg_replace to replace expressions within parentheses

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm using the following `preg_replace` syntax to replace the occurrence of expressions within parentheses.

```
$str = "(A or B) and ((C and D) or E)";
$str = preg_replace("#\([^()]*\)#", "$1", $str);
echo $str . "\n";
```

I expected the output to be: `$1 and ($2 or E)` instead I received `and ( or E)`. Why is it so and how should I modify in order to fix the issue?

Comment: `$1` is a reference to the first capturing group, which doesn't exists in your regex so it gets replaced with nothing. Take a look at `preg_replace_callback()` there you can pass a counter variable which you increment and use it as replacement

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it so

Rizier123 explained that above.

> and how should I modify in order to fix the issue?

```
$str = preg_replace_callback("#\([^()]*\)#",
                             function() { static $n; return '$'.++$n; }, $str);
```

`preg_replace_callback()` allows to generate a differently numbered replacement each time.